# Why is the text not adding in to the .txt file using python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am working on the 'ToDo list' project in python using CLI. I am struggling at the initial step. I have created all the necessaries connecting CLI and python (followed https://trstringer.com/easy-and-nice-python-cli/).

I wanted to add some data to the todo.txt file (already created and added in the same folder).
I used the following code in add.py

```
def add():
    note=input('Enter the todo you want to add: ')
    file1=open('todo.txt','w+')
    file1.write(note)
    file1.close()
```

And following for **main**.py

```
import sys
from .add import *

def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if len(args)==0:
        print('Enter the commands you needed here is help')
    else:
        for arg in args:
            if arg == '--add':
                add()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Set file

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = 'todo',
    version = '0.1.0',
    packages = ['todo'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'todo = todo.__main__:main'
        ]
    })
```

Added empty files of **init**.py. I think I did everything correctly but the input I took from the user is not adding to the todo.txt file. Please help me with this issue. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `file.close` is a method and you should use it as a call like `file.close()`, for more details you should read the python doc, ["7.2. Reading and Writing Files"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I didn't add the ~~~close()~~~ at the first place. I didn't work at that time. Later added just to confirm if it works. I made a try adding () as per your suggestion. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `close` function, like `file1.close()` to close the file properly. What you are doing is `file1.close` which does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I didn't add the ~~~close()~~~ at the first place. I didn't work at that time. Later added just to confirm if it works. I made a try adding () as per your suggestion. But that didn't work.